# Trying to display none, only hiding first instance of div

Tags: javascript

I have dynamically generated content which I'm outputting using two divs:

```
<div id="data1">Some info</div> -- <div id="data2">different info</div>
```

I want to only show "data2" in certain instances, so I'm trying to use JavaScript to hide it when it's not needed. Basically, my code is:

```
var getDivs = document.getElementById('data2');
IF STATEMENT {
   getDivs.style.display='none'; }
```

However, this is only kind of working - it's hiding the very first div that it comes across, but it's not hiding ALL of the divs with that ID.

This means that my code is basically correct - the IF STATEMENT is working, the display='none' DOES hide something, it's just not hiding everything that it should...

I tried to change it from div id= to div class= and instead use document.getElementByClassName('data2') but that doesn't seem to be working at all - it doesn't even hide the first .

What am I missing / doing wrong? What do I need to change to get this to hide all of the divs that are "data2"?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to suggestions of using jQuery? This would be a lot easier for you.

Comment: Element ID should be unique, use a class for multiple elements.

Comment: ids should be unique within a page. Give them all a class and use `document.getElementsByClassName`...

Comment: @Vache You should note that `document.getElementByClassName` will only work IE9 and up

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. You can see it works: http://js.do/code/zeek

Later Edit:
Using class instead of id:

```
<div id="data1">Some info</div> -- 
<div class="data2">different info</div>
<div class="data2">different info</div>
<div class="data2">different info</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 var getDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('data2');
 for(var i= 0; i< getDivs.length; i++){
    var div = getDivs[i];
    div.style.display='none';
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works when there is only one div to hide, but copy/paste the first line about 5-6 times and try it again. It only hides the first one.

Comment: @ZeekLTK attribute ID should be unique. Use class instead.

Comment: This works on the js.do/code site, but it's not working on my site for some reason.... hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and select by class instead of by ID. See http://api.jquery.com/class-selector.

jQuery is not only easy and readable, you'll also not write `getElementByClassName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#data2').hide();`

This assumes jQuery is on your page: http://api.jquery.com/

Note: You're going to have problems if this is dynamic and there are several elements with the ID of `data2`. Instead, use classes for selecting relevant divs if you can help it.